# How to keep the ASIHTTPRequestDelegate even when if the user popped from that view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I need to have a settings page,which has some credentials of the user then he can edit that.its a table view loading from an array taken from the httprequest.by clicking on each of this it will have the option to go to another view and update that value and come back. I have done the update call to the server on that update view like this..

```
 dispatch_async(backgroundQueue_, ^{
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(load) withObject:nil];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self showHUD];

            });
```

because in the mainqueue i am doing the popping back operation.so i need that update service to be called in the background.But the problem is when i coming back i am calling another service in the settings `viewcontroller`.to load the updated value.some times the delegates of the request is getting crashed.I am calling the service like this.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setPostValue:uidstr forKey:@"userId"];
     request.userInfo=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"update" forKey:@"type"];
    [request setPostValue:self.string forKey:@"age"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy|ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];
    [self showHUD1];    
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Can anybody point me how i can do this with out crashing my app.I think the problem is the delegate getting nil.

Answer (score 0):

Decouple your network requests from your view controller code. That way if the views are unloaded, the network delegate will still exist.

For example: Make a NetworkRequest singleton class that does all the communication with the network, and then you could use a mechanism like NSNotifications, or an @protocol interface in the singleton class that view controllers could become delegates of, to pass results and status changes as needed.

For a good tutorial on singletons in Objective-C, see: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Better drop usage of ASIHTTP since this framework is no longer supported by the developers. You won't get support for possible changes of future iOS versions.